# How to pack MagSafe cable to prevent its breaking?

Tags: macbook-pro, power, magsafe, third-party, maintenance

I am looking for a (most) powercord-safe way to pack my MagSafe adapter for a daily backpack commute.

Official Apple [recommendations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201600) (as illustrated by third-party videos like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3Z5wxJBafM)) don't prevent the breaks at all, as my experience with 2 MagSafes showed.

Third-party supplements promising a solution don't sound very convincing:

- [MagSavior](http://www.magsavior.com/pages/about-magsavior) is clearly a hard-plastic solution which just moves the cord breaking point farther from the adapter
- The [Fray Fix](http://www.thefrayfix.com/) seems [nearly impossible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GUY6WBG) to install despite looking promising after that

Answer (score 2):

One method I use on all my power adaptors is to loop the cable and secure it with a piece of Velcro. I will generally either keep folding the cable in half until it is a bit longer than fist size, or just loop it back and forth in a “S” pattern that is about fist size. I do NOT loop it in a circle.

I find these methods keep the cord safe and tangle free, allow quick deployment, and don’t put pressure where the cable comes out of the adaptor. I have never suffered from frayed cables using this method.  If you don’t have a Velcro strap, a rubber band will work.

Here's a photo of 2010 adapter that has been deployed around the world. Dirty, but fully functional, and no frays!

[image: 2010 MacBook Pro power adapter]

Comment: Thanks! Could you attach a photo demonstrating how it looks?

Answer (score 1):

One solution, if you can afford it, is to purchase another adapter and leave it at work. That's what I did after replacing one. Saves weight and bulk in the book bag, too!

Another idea is a plastic or metal case of just the right size to hold the adaptor without bending the cabling.

Reinforcing the ends with white gaffer's tape is also a solution. If you grew up taping your eye-glasses together because you were a nerd, this is a perfect solution.

Lastly, leaving a loop in the cable where it exits the adapter body, (as illustrated in the Apple page,) instead of a sharp bend, is the next best remedy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stephen Spencer: looping the cable loosely preserves it well. I also agree with IconDaemon that an additional adapter kept in the remote locations eases the back-and-forth transition.

My wife and I travel a lot. Here's how I do it:

All the cords and adapters I might need are carried in a small, easy-to-pack nylon case:

[image]

Opened, it looks like this:[image]

The power adapter is in one end compartment, with its cord passing around that side of the case to where it's coiled in the end space. Other bits (a thin Ethernet cable, a Thunderbolt adapter, a two-prong octopus, an iPhone wall charger, two extra Lightning cables (one long, one short) and a black case for my earphones are also included.

For a trip with a specific need at destination, add what you need. I just returned from Panama and Paraguay, and took (and have now removed) several appropriate plug adapters.

I carry the case in my daypack, along with the other keep-it-close-stuff like the MacBook Air, my purse, medicines, and Kindle.